# How to shift 2d array column up in c program

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, swap

I need shift the column up in 2D Array and set the last row to zero.

if I call shift up once need to move the each column value to up and set the last column to zero.
input array   output array

```
1 2 3         4 5 6 
4 5 6  ==>    7 8 9
7 8 9         1 1 1
1 1 1         0 0 0
```

used swap logic bit the last row becomes first after calling shift UP.

```
void shiftup()
{
for(int col=0;col<=3;col++)

   {
       int start = 0;
       int end = 3 - 1;
       while (start < end) {
          swap(&arr[start][col], &arr[end][col]);
          start++;
          end--;
   }
}
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

can any one suggest the change in the above code.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Please show a [mcve] along with actual result.

Comment: I suspect `col<=3` should be `col<3`.

Comment: [Edit] your question instead of posting in a comment.

Comment: Also, why are you swapping? You should copy instead.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put all relevent information _there_ and not in comments where formatting is not possible

Comment: i am getting output as below.
input array
{{1 2 3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{1,1,1},}
output array:
{{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{1,1,1},{1 2 3}}
expected output:
{{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{1,1,1},{0,0,0}}

Comment: **[Edit] your question and put all relevant information into the question**. You cannot have multiline comments with correct formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler to apply standard functions `memmove` and `memset` as for example

```
    memmove( a, a + 1, sizeof( a ) - sizeof( a[0] ) );
    memset( a + 3, 0, sizeof( *a ) );
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h >

int main( void )
{
    enum { M = 4, N = 3 };
    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 },
        { 1, 1, 1 }
    };

    memmove( a, a + 1, sizeof( a ) - sizeof( a[0] ) );
    memset( a + M - 1, 0, sizeof( *a ) );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
4 5 6
7 8 9
1 1 1
0 0 0
```

As for your code then at least this for loop

```
for(int col=0;col<=3;col++)
              ^^^^^^
```

is incorrect. You have to write instead

```
for(int col = 0;col < 3;col++)
```

And these calling of the function swap

```
swap(&arr[start][col], &arr[end][col]);
```

does not make a sense.

Comment: Thanks for the logic ..it is working as expected.
can same logic will work for shift down?

Comment: @user1897937 You can use the same function memove to shift down.

Comment: for Shiftdown is the below logic correct?
memmove( a + M -1 , a + 1, sizeof( a ) - sizeof( a[0] ) );
memset( a  , 0, sizeof( *a ) );

Comment: @user1897937 You need to write memmove( a + 1, a, sizeof( a ) - sizeof( *a ) );
        memset( a, 0, sizeof( *a ) );

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you please suggest similar logic for left shift of column and setting the last column of each row to zero using memmove

Comment: @user1897937 You can ask a new question with a description of your problem.

Comment: Could you please check the question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942492/how-to-shift-2d-array-column-to-left-in-c-program