# How to shift 2d array column to left in c program

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, function-definition

I need shift the column of each row left in 2D Array and setting the last column of each row to zero

if I call shift left once need to move the each column value to left and set the last column of each row zero. input array output array.

```
1 2 3         2 3 0 
4 5 6  ==>    5 6 0
7 8 9         8 9 0
1 1 1         1 1 0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Loops, one row ar a time...

Comment: Tried below logic but it is like rotation not setting last column of each Row to zero
for (size_t i = 1; i < M* N; i++)
      {
         arr[i-1] = arr[i];
      }

Answer (score 2):

You can write a separate function that shifts elements of a one-dimensional array and sets the last element to zero.

Then you can call the function for each "row" of the two-dimensional array.

The function can look for example the following way

```
void shift_left( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n-- )
    {
        memmove( a, a + 1, n * sizeof( *a ) );
        a[n] = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void shift_left( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if (n--)
    {
        memmove( a, a + 1, n * sizeof( *a ) );
        a[n] = 0;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { M = 4, N = 3 };

    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 },
        { 1, 1, 1 }
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++) shift_left( a[i], N );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
1 1 1

2 3 0
5 6 0
8 9 0
1 1 0
```